# JIRA - get all fields for project and issue type

Tags: java, jira

I want to get all default (not custom) fields available for specific project and issue type. Field set depends on issue type, but also on project. For custom fields there's no trouble, but for default fields I can't find solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you looking for default fields that are not hidden in Field Configuration of a Project ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for that, but Field Configuration have to match also to issue type (for example: bug, improvement). If you're interested, look at my answer, I found solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found something like that:

```
    MutableIssue issuePattern = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueFactory.class).getIssue();
    issuePattern.setProjectId(projectId);
    issuePattern.setIssueTypeId(issueTypeId);

    IssueCreationHelperBean issueCreationHelperBean = ComponentAccessor.getComponentOfType(IssueCreationHelperBean.class);
    List<OrderableField> availableFields = issueCreationHelperBean.getFieldsForCreate(loggedInUser, issuePattern);
```

and it works for sure. I hope that it will be useful for someone else. I've tested it under JIRA 5.